Control tools in holoviews (bokeh backend) with overlayed plots
This is an extension of How to control active tools in holoviews with bokeh backend, but applied to overlayed plots. It seems like all plots need to specify the same set of tools to get what you want.
E. g. I would like to get rid of the wheel-zoom altogether, but have box zoom activated. Additionally fullscreen, crosshair and reset should be in the tools list.
The options for this are: .opts(tools=['fullscreen', 'crosshair', 'reset'], default_tools=["box_zoom"])
Minimum working example:
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

p1 = hv.Curve([1, 3, 2])
p2 = hv.Curve([4, 6, 6])
(p1 * p2)

This yields the following (standard) toolbar: 
Now, put the .opts at the overlay:
(p1 * p2).opts(tools=['fullscreen', 'crosshair', 'reset'], default_tools=["box_zoom"])

This doesn't change anything, only the wheel-zoom is not active any more: 
Now, additionally supply one of the unterlying plots with our opts:
(p1.opts(tools=['fullscreen', 'crosshair', 'reset'], default_tools=["box_zoom"]) * p2).opts(tools=['fullscreen', 'crosshair', 'reset'], default_tools=["box_zoom"])

This gets us a bit further, since now the tools I want are present. Unfortunatey, the other tools as well: 
Finally, provide all plots with the options:
(p1.opts(tools=['fullscreen', 'crosshair', 'reset'], default_tools=["box_zoom"]) 
 * p2.opts(tools=['fullscreen', 'crosshair', 'reset'], default_tools=["box_zoom"])
).opts(tools=['fullscreen', 'crosshair', 'reset'], default_tools=["box_zoom"])

This gets us what we want: 
Is there a better way to get exactly the tools I want?
